# Redirecting URL asks for credentials twice

Tags: credentials

We have a "SharePoint" like URL we will nickname a.sp.com, which redirects to the appropriate port number.

Marketing wants to set up "b.sp.com" to redirect to "a.sp.com". When we do this, it asks in Firefox and safari to login twice. How can I set up "b.sp.com" to bypass that and just use credentials from "a.sp.com"

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create new web site in IIS, bind it to b.sp.com with anonymous authentication and redirect users from that site to a.sp.com using IIS **HTTP Redirect** functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The URL Rewrite module is a nice tool that keeps you physically out of your web.config file. As a second reminder, URL Rewrite is a GUI for writing information into your web.config file. It is always best to make a copy of your web.config file before making any changes (GUI based or manually). 
After you hit the Apply link, this is what has been added to the IIS site's web.config file,  Please refer this link its similar to your issue

http://pcfromdc.blogspot.in/2013/10/how-to-redirect-from-http-to-https-with.html